# Who should have responsibility for populating data on usercontrol?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I feel kinda stupid for asking this, but i'm having trouble finding the best solution for this:

In a WPF application i have a window that holds a usercontrol. The usercontrol has a ListBox and a DataGrid. The ListBox is populated from a StaticResource and whenever something is selected in the ListBox, a lookup in a service is made that returns data to be populated in the DataGrid.

Ok. I can easily raise an event in the usercontrol and have the main window listen in on that. That window could then look up the data in the service and then call some populate/databind method on the usercontrol which can then update its DataGrid. That places all responsibility on the main window.

I do like seperation of concern ;) and this is not something that the main window should care about. If this had not been a usercontrol i would have used denpendency injection to give it a reference to the service that can get the data.

What do you think i should do? If i'm to go the DI-way, how would i inject the service in my usercontrol (i can think of a couple ways, but what is best-practice?) Any good reads on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted way of doing this is creating ViewModels (based on MVVM architecture). ViewModels are objects that are designed specifically for data-binding.

Some reading on the subject:

[Starting Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

[A framework for MVVM](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Comment: yikes! thanks for the info. I think for this small app i might find a simpler solution. But definately something i'll read up on :)

Comment: Once you get used to it you can do it just as fast using MVVM :)